# Access the main root folder through add on domain folder

Tags: php, hosting

I am hosting two website on shared hosting. One is main and other is as add on domain. The main is placed under main root `public_html`, and the Add on is under `public_html/AddOnWebsite`. I also have a folder named Uploads under `public_html` to store all the files.

Public_html/
1) Main Website
 
2) Uploads
3) Addon Website

From main website, when I try to download the files from Uploads, it works. However, from `Add On Website`, it doesn't go through. I tested the following code on localhost offline, it was working perfectly fine but on live site, it takes me to add on website index page.

PhP code file under websiteName (Addon Domain) folder

```
$dir = "../Uploads/";

if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755);
} else {
    $files = scandir($dir, 0);
    $count=1;
    for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++)
    echo  $count++ ."<a href='"$dir.$files[$i]."'>".$files[$i]."</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: I suspect 2 things are happening.. 
$dir = "../Uploads/";  /should probably be full path, rather than relative..
$dir = "/home/username/public_html/Uploads/";
Also, likely each Apache process is owned by the user that owns the domain, so permissions on the Uploads directory would need to be such that both "users" have full write privledges

Comment: Thanks Duane, yes, both users have same access.. 0644 for individual files, 0755 for folders... Let me try the other thing you have mentioned. Like I said, it is working absolutely fine on localhost (windows machine) I have linux server online though. Don't know if that would aid something as extra info

Comment: Well, I used `realpath("../Uploads")`, and it gives the following link http://addonwebsite/home/user_name/public_html/Uploads/test.docx, but again not working...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$dir = __DIR__."/../Uploads/";

if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755);
} else {
    $files = scandir($dir, 0);
    $count=1;
    for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++)
    echo  $count++ ."<a href='"$dir.$files[$i]."'>".$files[$i]."</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah Nantha, I have already tried __DIR__ and realpath(), both are giving  `http://example.com/home/user_name/public_html/Uploads/test.docx`. If I just use `../Uploads` then it gives `http://example.com/Uploads/test.docx` and still don't work. I don't know if I can link back to main directory

Comment: By the way If I place the upload folder under Add on domain folder and then try to reach it, it works and I have access to all files.. it's like connecting Upload | Addonwebsite > Php Code  as add on website folder is parallel to Upload folder, ../Upload should work to access upload folder from addonwebsite